# On getting api data from DS.RESTAdapter into model

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js, ember-data

Happily, I can get Ember to talk to a CORS rest api and return data. For a simple JSON Object it returns a message object as in: http://jsbin.com/cakih/1/edit. Yet when I try to modify the working code get a some records into a model I do not succeed.

It might be I've botched the view. Here I tried just getting one field as well as a field from all the rows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <p>
    user.email: {{fistObject.email}}
  </p>
  <ul>
    {{#each user in users}}
      <li>
        blah
        {{user.name}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

Or perhaps I missed something in the javascript. Do I have to create a model that includes every field returned?:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    console.log(this.store.find('user'));RESTAdapter
    return this.store.find('user');
  }
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  role: DS.attr('string')
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  //host: 'http://10.0.1.24:3000',
  host: 'http://parleyvale.com:3000',
  //host: 'https://stuff2get.parleyvale.com',
  namespace: 'api',
  ajax: function(url, method, hash) {
    //hash.crossDomain = true;
    //hash.xhrFields = {withCredentials: true};
    return this._super(url, method, hash).then(function(json) {
      console.log({users: json});
      return {users: json};http://jsbin.com/pubun/1/edit
    });
  }
});

App.UserAdapter = App.ApplicationAdapter.extend({
  pathForType: function(){
    return 'users';
  }
});
```

The array of 4 record is getting to Ember, I can see them in the console.log The non-working multiple record version is here: http://jsbin.com/pubun/1/edit. The record array can be seen on the server here: http://parleyvale.com:3000/api/users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax would probably work just fine, you just have two small errors in your template.

`firstObject` is missing the `r`.  And in the template your model isn't known as `users`, but `model`.  `users` would be some property that exists on the object returned from the model hook.

```
<p>
    user.email: {{firstObject.email}}
  </p>
  <ul>
    {{#each user in model}}
      <li>
        blah
        {{user.name}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

Just as a FYI, fixing your payload should happen in the serializer, like

```
App.UserSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
    payload = {users:payload};
    return this._super(store, type, payload);
  }
});
```

You can read more about what to do at http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_extractArray, and https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

http://jsbin.com/xageniye/1/edit